# System error: missing of libgcc_s_dw2.dll

Tags: omnet++

i use omnetpp-4.6 , sumo0.22.0 and veins-4a2. Since three months ago, the simulator was executed correctly.

Today when I tried to execute the simulation example, I got the following error:

**Unable to start the program as it lacks libgcc_s_dw2.dll on your computer. Try reinstalling the program to correct this problem.**

Why I has this problem now and what should I do to resolve this problem please?
Help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: did you check if this problem persists across re-installation of OMNeT++? Does the problem only manifest on your machine?

Comment: I reinstalled OMNet++ and it is working well now. Thank you Sir.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073878/4707703