# OMNET++ 4.6 recurrent error appeared: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll?

Tags: omnet++

[image: Recurrent Error in omnet4.6]

How to solve this error? The only way I solve is by reinstalling the omnet again and again then after few days the same error appears. I find everywhere in the internet but can not find the exact solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I found that the " libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" is in my installed directory F:\Omnet\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin  . What might went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You **have to** start the simulations and the IDE also from the MINGwEnv prompt otherwise the PATH is nit set properly and your simulations will not find the mentioned DLL.

Comment: I start the IDE from the MINGwEnv promp. Simulation runs for several times but it crashes after few days. I dont understand what is going wrong. I always have to reinstall omnet from the begining. Can you help me on this issue.

Comment: Does the same problem manifest on a different computer? Could it be that something on your computer (a virus, perhaps) is changing files?

Comment: I think I dont have a virus but I run "Malwarebytes-AntiMalware". This problem occurs only sometimes when i forcefully close the simulation window. I have installed new omnet again so far there is no problem.